# Is it possible to add extra columns to fields in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

We are looking to extend MySQL by adding extra columns to each "column". Right now you have the following.

```
Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
```

We want to be able to add to the "column" definition an extra column like, `Attributes`. Our system has certain design specifications that we need to describe more data per "column". How can we accomplish this in MySQL?

The query to return back all of the columns is as follows.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM MyDB.MyTable;
```

**EDIT 1**

I should have added this to begin with, and I apologize for not doing so. We are currently describing attributes in the Comments section for each column type, and we understand that this is a very dirty solution, but it was the only one we could think of at the time. We have built a code generator that revolves around the DB structure and is what really stems from this initiative. We want to describe code attributes for a column so the code generator can pick up the changes and refresh the code base on each change or run.

Comment: add extra fields to the table, don't break mysql itself. "field", "field_foo", "field_bar", etc...

Comment: MySQL doesn't have fields. It has columns and tables.  Often the world field is used as a synonym for column. It's not clear what you need to do here.

Comment: @MarcB We want to assign attributes to each column in a table. Adding "field_foo" for "field" would repeat the same data over and over again for each row.

Comment: Are you talking about being able to add metadata about the columns themselves (i.e. one metadata entry per column regardless of number of rows in table), or are you looking to have additional columns where each record would hold a value for that column?

Comment: @MikeBrant Looking to add metadata per column regardless of rows

Comment: @meanbunny Why not just store the metadata in another table? Or add the metadata in the application code, as the application code should understand the columns in the database tables it is accessing.

Comment: @MikeBrant Well the code generator itself reflects the DB and creates our data structures for the application. I am noticing that creating metadata in another table might be our best and safest route.

Comment: Code generation may be a useful to to generate concept proofs or to base/seed classes from which you can work, but I imagine you will ultimately find you will need to have some way to define custom code behaviors that won't be generated by a code generator.  You may be running into this now.

Comment: @MikeBrant That is true, and thankfully we have `partial` classes for this problem to work around in C#. In my experience so far it has provided us with extreme rapid development for new features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, terminology: "field" and "column" are basically synonyms in this context. There is no distinction between fields and columns. Some MySQL commands even allow you to use these two words interchangeably (e.g. `SHOW FIELDS FROM MyDB.MyTable`).

> We want to assign attributes to each column in a table. Adding "field_foo" for "field" would repeat the same data over and over again for each row.

**Simple answer:**
If you want more attributes that pertain to a given column `foo`, then you should create another table, where `foo` is its primary key, so each distinct value gets exactly one row. This is part of the process of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). This allows you to have attributes to describe a given value of `foo` without repeating data, even when you use that value many times in your original table.

---

It sounds like you might also need to allow for extensibility and you want to allow new columns at some future time, but you don't know which columns or how many right now. This is a pretty common project requirement.

You might be interested in my presentation [Extensible Data Modeling](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling), in which I give an overview of different solutions in SQL for this type of problem.

- Extra Columns
- Entity-Attribute-Value
- Class Table Inheritance
- Serialized LOB
- Inverted Indexes
- Online Schema Changes
- Non-Relational Databases

None of these solutions are foolproof, each has their strengths and weaknesses. So it is worth learning about all of them, and then decide which ones have strengths that matter to your specific project, while their weaknesses are something that doesn't inconvenience you too much (that's the decision process for many software design choices).

---

> We are currently describing attributes in the Comments section for each column type

So you're using something like the "Serialized LOB" solution.

Comment: Where is Entity-Attribute-Value on the site? That sounds like what we want to do.

Comment: @meanbunny, before you consider using EAV, read this article: [Bad CaRMa](http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/).

Comment: We initially did create another table for extra properties relating to an object but in the situation of the real object we wanted to keep the DB structure as simple as possible. Hence the quest to possibly extend MySQL. I am going to read over the articles you have posted now.

Comment: @meanbunny, database normalization is simpler by some measure. It results in an extra table for each of the attributes you want to add fields to, but it reduces the redundant storage of information that you also say you want to avoid, and therefore eliminates possibility of data anomalies.

Comment: @BillKarwin - really appreciated your slide set. i was not aware of inverted indexes as a way of addressing some of the cons associated with serialized LOBs. best regards